# Adapt container to resized image

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image that I resize based on the height of the device. I would like to have the area under to adapt and be the same width as the resized image. How can I do that? Thanks, your help is very much appreciated!

[example tablet (portrait)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlvKz.png)

[example tablet (landscape)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOemF.png)

[example mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDRXE.png)

```
Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: heigth / 3,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/image.png', width: 619, height: 422),
          ),
        ),
        // What to do to have this widget be the same width as the above one?
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding what I was looking for. I'm not sure if it is the ideal solution but that is going to work for me (at least for now :) ).

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      double imageHeight = constraints.maxHeight / 3;

      return Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: imageHeight * (619 / 422),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                height: imageHeight,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/image.png', width: 619, height: 422),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Thank you to you both @pskink and @Sanchit Batra to have taken the time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of telling the width of the image explicitly in the attribute, what you may do is store that number in a variable that you assign to the container below as well. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for you reply. The width and height specified in Image.asset are in actuality not the dimensions of the image displayed on the screen. The image size adapts to the device height as per the parent Container and the FittedBox. I should not have included those in the code snippet to avoid any confusio. It was to tix the following issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340675/failed-assertion-width-0-0-is-not-true-when-placing-single-image-in-containe